# Weinre missing in browser sync

Tags: browser-sync, weinre

I have latest browser sync installed. I run it in the most simple way, but I didn't see weinre.

I tested a many ways I didn't undestand. In all articles about browser sync is the toggle just there without any extra setup. As you can see on screen https://snag.gy/NrgcfL.jpg there is no toggle.

Simple setup

```
bs.init({
    server: 'app',
    files: ['app/css/*.css']
});
```

Try to add weinre port

```
bs.init({
    server: 'app',
    files: ['app/css/*.css'],    
    ui: {
        "port": 3001,
        "weinre": {
            "port": 3002
        }
    }
});
```

My real scenario

```
"browser-sync": "browser-sync start --proxy localhost:54661 --port 54662 --ui-port 54663 --no-open --no-inject-changes --files=\"Content/*.css\" \"Content/*.js\" \"Views/**/*.html\""
```

Answer (score 2):

weinre was removed from BrowserSync; see this GH issue:

https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/1413#issuecomment-352859886